# Confusion implementing chebyshev type 2 band pass filter in matlab

Tags: matlab, filters, filter-design

I want to design a band pass Chebyshev Type II filter using analog prototyping. The order of filter is 20 with a value of 60 dB stop band attenuation and 0.75 dB pass band ripple where,
Pass band edge = 800 Hz
Stop band edge = 2000 Hz
Sampling frequency = 6000

My Matlab code is below

```
clc;  close all;   clear all;
Rp = 0.75;    Rs = 60;
fp = 800;
fs = 2000;
Fs = 6000;

fn = Fs/2;     % nyquist frequency
wp = fp/fn;     % normalized Pass band corner frequency
ws = fs/fn;     % normalized Stop band corner frequency

[n,Wn] = cheb2ord(wp,ws,Rp,Rs);
[num,den] = cheby2(20,Rs,Wn);
freqz(num,den,512,Fs);
```

**I have also attached snapshot of output which shows that output  frequency plot looks like low pass,but i think ,why output plot is not band pass?How can it look band pass?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the function `cheb2ord` in the wrong way. Assuming that your lower stopband edge is $800$ Hz and your upper stopband edge is $2000$ Hz (note that a bandpass filter has two stopband edges, as well as two passband edges), and if the sampling frequency is $6000$ Hz, then the following command should do what you intended to do:

`[b, a] = cheby2(10, 60, [4, 10]/15);`

Note that for bandpass and bandstop filters, the resulting filter order is twice the number you use in the call to `cheby2`.

Comment: it might be nice to explain where the numbers "10", "60", "4", "10", and "15: come from when the relevant parameters are 6000 Hz, 800 Hz, 2000 Hz..

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Maybe a bit too nice, considering that this might be part of some homework project? Also, from the OP's code it appears that computing normalized edge frequencies is not the problem here. Concerning the value for the filter order ($10$), I tried to explain this choice in the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: @MattL. Please believe me ,it is not part of any home work, i understood "10" and "60", but still confused why you used [4,10]/15 ??

Comment: @engr: These are exactly the same value you used in your code: `fp/fn`, `fs/fn`

Comment: ok thanks, you re wrote them in lowest form by cancelling common factor

Comment: Yeah, but @MattL. your answer is s'posed to serve a wider interest than that of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

What variables *n* and *Wn* holds when returned from **cheb2ord** and, what you do with these values? I.e. check documentation for: [cheb2ord](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/cheb2ord.html) and [cheby2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/cheby2.html).